# CMake + gcc: libraries with same "signature"

Tags: c++, gcc, cmake

Assuming the following directory structure:

```
 -- CMakeLists.txt (1)
 -- source
 ---- CMakeLists.txt (2)
 ---- view
 ------ terminal
 -------- window.cpp
 ------ sdl
 -------- window.cpp
 -- include
 ---- CMakeLists.txt (3)
 ---- view
 ------ terminal
 -------- window.h
 ------ sdl
 -------- window.h
```

I'm trying to create an application that supports two visual representations: **a SDL based one** and a **text based (Terminal) one**

Now I know that I can select the appropriate headers/source files using CMake instructions in both (2) and (3) and using the appropriate **add_directory()** directive.

Everything works fine on the CMake side, the problem lies on the gcc side:

> fatal error: View/Window.h: No such file or directory
>    #include "View/Window.h"

And this is of course to be expected since I haven't updated my .cpp files yet; I simply do not know what the best course of action from here:

- Invert the orders of directories e.g. SDL/View/Window.h instead of
  View/SDL/Window.h ..?
- Nest the .cpp with the .h and use relative paths ..?
- Something else

Of course what I'm trying to accomplish here is a seamless usage of Window.h, independently of the chosen rendering library; something along the lines of:

```
#include "View/Window.h" // Could be terminal or SDL
auto window = new Window();
window->ShowText("Stack");
// ...
```

I have a feeling this problem is a problem of structure; having not fully grasped CMake I probably do not get most of its concepts and thus this is probably unrelated to gcc.

Roughly summed up:

**What is a working CMake/cpp approach when working with multiple (graphical) libraries?**

Comment: I believe the problem is you are missing a include_directories() entry in your CMakeLists.txt.

Comment: @drescherjm If you're refering to the (1) here is what's included:
`include_directories(
  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}
  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include
  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/source
  )`

Along with 
`add_subdirectory("include")
add_subdirectory("source")`